# what is the x86 opcode for assembly variables and constants?

Tags: variables, assembly, x86, intel, opcodes

i know that every instruction has opcodes. 
i could find opcodes for mov , sub instructions.
but what is the opcode for variables and it's types.
we use assembler directives to define a variable and constant? 
how they are represented in x86 opcodes?

#### nasm assembler x86:

`segment .bss 
largest resb 2  ; reserves two bytes for largest

segment .data
number1 DW 12345 ; defines a constant number1`

i tried online this https://defuse.ca/online-x86-assembler.htm#disassembly assembly to opcode conveter. but when i used nasm code to define a variable it shows error!

Comment: each assembler (the program that reads the assembly language) defines its own assembly language, so you have to look at what a particular assembler uses for its syntax....by reading the manual...or googling.

Comment: `DW` and `resb` are not "true" assembly instructions, they have no corresponding machine instruction or "opcode". They are *pseudo* instructions that are handled internally by the assembler program. I suggest you do some more research about assemblers and how they work.

Answer (score 4):

There's no opcode for variables. There are even no variables in machine code.

There is CPU and memory. Memory contains some values (bytes).

The CPU has `cs:ip` instruction pointer, pointing to memory address, where is the next instruction to execute, so it will read byte(s) from that address, and **interpret** them as opcode, and execute it as an instruction.

Whether you have in memory stored data or machine code doesn't matter, both are byte values.

What makes part of memory "data" or "variable" is the logical interpretation created by the running code, it's the code which does use certain part of memory only as "data/variables" and other part of memory as "code" (or eventually as both at the same time, like in [this DOS 51B](http://ped.7gods.org/GREECE.ASM) long COM code drawing Greece flag on screen, where the `XLAT` instruction is using the code opcodes also as source data for blue/white strips configuration).

Whether you write in your source:

```
x:
    add     al,al
```

or

```
x:
    db 0x00, 0xC0
```

Doesn't matter, the resulting machine code is identical (in both cases the CPU will execute `add al,al` when pointed to that memory to be executed as instruction, and `mov ax,[x]` will set `ax` to `0xC000` in both cases, when used as "variable".

You may want to check listing file from the assembler (`-l <listing_file_name>` command line option for `nasm`) to see yourself there's no way to tell which bytes are code and which are data.

Comment: thank you!  but in high level programming languages we declare lot of variables . when it is converted into machine language , if there is no variable , how it will keep track of all the data?

Comment: The compiler does produce CODE which creates that logical-construct of some piece of memory working as constant/variable. In some cases, like advanced data types/classes (`std::map`) it may be LOT of code. If there's some bug in such code, it would break the illusion and you would get weird behaviour during runtime, so the compilers must be very good at producing "correct" code (from the high level language definition point of view, for example C++ has definition of abstract machine, which the language is modifying and the compiler implements this abstract machine for particular platform).

Comment: Usually such code for particular type of variable takes internally as input "pointer" or "reference" (technically memory address), which marks first byte of memory reserved for particular instance of such variable. I.e. `int i = 123;` in C++ may reserve 4 bytes of memory to store value `123` (although the compiler may also decide to keep the value only in register, without reserving memory at all), and then code `++i;` will increment value in that memory. In such case the reservation+pointer can be emitted by compiler in quite hardcoded way, like having that "i" at fixed local stack position.

Answer (score 2):

Assembler directives like `segment`, `resb`, or `dw` are not instructions and do not correspond to opcodes. That's why they are *directives* instead of *instructions*. Roughly speaking, there are two kinds of directives:

- one kind of directive *configures the assembler*. For example, the `segment` directive configures the assembler to continue assembly in the section you provided.
- another kind of directive *emits data*. For example, the `dw` directive emits the given datum into the object file.  This can be used to place arbitrary data into memory for use with your program.